# LotusScript Notesdomparser behaviour is strange

Tags: xml, lotus-notes, lotusscript

System: Note 8.5.3

I have received a XML string from Notes Email and would like to process it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LongerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrTag>ExtremelyLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLong Content</LongerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrTag>
```

This one shows an error of expected tag error,
when the following script run

```
 NotesDomParser.Process()
```

and from which, I find no errors in other languages nor platforms.

What is your solution to this bug?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can get full error message then use "Print NotesDomParser.Log()". You must have this line in your error handler point.

Comment: It just show "<?xml version='1.0'?><DOMParserLog><fatalerror source='NotesInputSource' line='20' column='81'>Expected end of tag 'sometag'</fatalerror><error>DOM parser operation failed</error></DOMParserLog>", which I have no problem parsing this xml in other platforms nor languages
Seems there is an unexpected character added when character length = 81?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it.. You can open this XML in Notepad++(View - > Show symbol -> Show all Characters) and see what it.

Comment: UltraEdit includes a hex editing capability that will show you the Unicode values of everything in the file. I don't know, however, if that feature is included in the free trial version. I've also used HdX for hex editing/viewing. Check the first few bytes of the file to see if there's a Byte Order Mark there in addition to checking out what's in the position where the end of the tag is expected.

Comment: My copy of NotePad++ also has an Hex converter on the plugins menu. From playing around a bit, it looks like you have to select the text you want to convert, and select Converter\ASCII->HEX from the Plugins menu. Looks like it probably came from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/

Comment: @user3363807 Do you really think it's a string length issue? That would be weird but, as a mentor once told me, "Go with what works, not with what makes sense." Is 'sometag' the complete tag or is it truncated? Can you try mocking up XML tag and content of the same length?

Comment: I have used a script to truncate all the special characters and it still doesn't work. It seems the processing engine is weird.

Comment: @user3363807 ... ok, you can use Java for this. You can write javaLib in DDE and call methods by LS2J or run java-agent.

Comment: @PaulOlesh hmmm it seems it is the best solution...